# how to find the first instance of PID from logs in bash

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have set of logs like following:

```
sept 4 00:00:00 ntp[123]: some message like send start
sept 4 00:00:00 ntp[123]: some message like starting
sept 4 00:00:01 ntp[123]: some message like started
sept 4 00:00:01 dhcp[234]: some message like i am server
sept 4 00:00:02 dhcp[234]: some message like i am client
sept 4 00:00:05 ntp[345]: some message this line is special
sept 4 00:00:08 bash[555]: some message like any message
sept 4 00:00:08 bash[555]: some message like any message
sept 4 00:00:09 bash[555]: some message like any message
sept 4 00:00:10 GLITCH bash[556]: some message like any message
sept 4 00:00:10 bash[555]: some message like any message
```

Exmpected output:

```
sept 4 00:00:00 ntp[123] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:01 dhcp[234] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:05 ntp[345] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:10 bash[556]: started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:10 bash[555] started or respawned
```

from the above set of logs, I need to find the processes which are either spawned or respawned.I have to do this with the offline set of logs.

With following I can only print the processes and their PID , but I need **timestamp  as well**:

```
grep -Po '\w+\[\d+\]' local.log |awk '!a[$0]++ {print $0 , "respawned or started "}'
ntp[123] respawned or started
dhcp[234] respawned or started
ntp[345] respawned or started
bash[556] started or respawned
bash[555] respawned or started
```

any hints ?

**Note: This will not help , as `process[PID]` location varies per line.**

```
awk '!a[$4]++ {print $1,$2,$3 , "respawned or started "}'
```

Comment: but if `process[PID]` can be in arbitrary position, so datetime can be also anywere? You should update your question to present a more "real" input log where your crucial fields are in arbitrary position

Comment: no, datetime will be at start in same format as mentioned.  anything post that is dynamic. So I think , I need to get the regex for `process[pid]` and then use it but not sure how to do that.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest added `sept 4 00:00:10 GLITCH bash[556]: some message like any message` to the question to showing better input.

Comment: why always downvote ?what is wrong !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '!a[$2]++ {print $1 "[" $2 "] started or respawned"}' local.log
sept 4 00:00:00 ntp[123] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:01 dhcp[234] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:05 ntp[345] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:08 bash[555] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:10 GLITCH bash[556] started or respawned
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[][]'`

  This tells awk to use `[` or `]` as field separators.  In this was, the process ID will be field 2, `$2`.

  *In more depth:* In regular expressions, `[...]` matches any of the characters inside of the square brackets.  In our case, we want the characters in the group to be `[` and `]`, so we write `[][]`.  We can do this because the rule is that `]` does not end a group if it is the first character in the group.
- `!a[$2]++ {print $1 "[" $2 "] started or respawned"}`

  `a[$2]` is the number of times that we have seen process ID `$2` so far.  `!a[$2]++` will be true for the first time and false thereafter.

  *In more depth:* `a[$2]` is zero the first time we encounter the PID and positive thereafter.  In awk, zero is false and nonzero is true.  We want the opposite of this: we want to print when a[$2] is zero.  Therefore, we negate the logical condition with `!`.  Then, `!a[$2]` is true only when `a[$2]` is zero.  The trailing `++` increments `a[$2]` but only after the logical value has been evaluated.

  When `!a[$2]++` is true, awk will perform the command in braces which prints the desired output.

### Alternative

Using `printf` to format the output in place of `print`:

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '!a[$2]++{printf "%s[%s] started or respawned\n",$1,$2}' local.log
sept 4 00:00:00 ntp[123] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:01 dhcp[234] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:05 ntp[345] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:08 bash[555] started or respawned
sept 4 00:00:10 GLITCH bash[556] started or respawned
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk** solution (will work on most awk implementations):

```
awk 'match($0, /\<[[:alnum:]]+\[[0-9]+\]:/){ pid=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH); 
     if(!a[pid]++) print $1,$2,$3,pid" respawned or started" }' logfile
```

The output:

```
sept 4 00:00:00 ntp[123]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:01 dhcp[234]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:05 ntp[345]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:08 bash[555]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:10 bash[556]: respawned or started
```

---

Or GNU **awk** solution:

```
awk 'match($0, /^([[:alpha:]]+ [0-9]+ ([0-9]{2}:?){3}).*\<([[:alnum:]]+\[[0-9]+\]:)/, a) 
     && !b[a[3]]++{ print a[1],a[3]" respawned or started" }' logfile
```

The output:

```
sept 4 00:00:00 ntp[123]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:01 dhcp[234]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:05 ntp[345]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:08 bash[555]: respawned or started
sept 4 00:00:10 bash[556]: respawned or started
```

Comment: @monk, you have made confusion with your new condition. If you really consider `GLITCH bash[556]` as a process name - that's unpredictable logic, cause in that case, it could be `SUBNAME HERE GLITCH bash[556]`. How can one know how much words should process name occupy?!!! I feel regret helping you. Disappointed from all of this ...

Comment: I am really sorry about it, my english is not good sometimes, but those are the conditions, I mentioned, "except timestamp position everything is dynamic". Also,I noticed downvots including my  old question, strange my current deed could result in past deeds. In the end, I am learner so forgive my mistakes.